# Getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getDomAttribute for Select in Selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

I am etting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getDomAttribute for Select in Selenium 4.. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? my selenium version is 4.6.0. Tried multiple things but nothing worked..

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getDomAttribute at org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getDomAttribute(WebElement.java:131) at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:54)`

Comment: you'll probably need to call getWrappedElement() first as Select is a class object and not a direct webelement reference: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getDomAttribute
at org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getDomAttribute(WebElement.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:54)
```

...indicates a dependency conflict and it's almost always a dependency management issue.

`getDomAttribute()` is a new addition in [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4).

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- Your project is updated with the latest [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) release. (current release being ***v4.10.0***)
- Your project is correctly using the same version of [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) libraries for everything and resolve the dependency conflicts following the article [HOW TO DEBUG DEPENDENCY CONFLICTS IN MAVEN AND GRADLE](https://www.javaadvent.com/2020/12/how-to-debug-dependency-conflicts-in-maven-and-gradle.html)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [[ Bug]: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getDomAttribute while using select in Selenium 4](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10905)
- [[ Bug]: Getting UnsupportedOperationException when while selecting values from dropdowns in selenium-4.0.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10290)